# How to pivot the table containing each value in the output row in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can't resolve this issue. I tried to use PIVOT() function, I've read the documentation and tried to use that. Additionally, I tried to find the answer but didn't find.

The main problem is using PIVOT() function, that it has to include **aggregation** function, but I needn't it, I need **only pivot** the table without **any aggregation**.

The source table:

| COUNTRY | LEVEL | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | High | 22 |
| Germany | Medium | 5 |
| Germany | Low | 3 |
| Italy | High | 43 |
| Italy | Medium | 21 |
| Italy | Low | 8 |
| Canada | High | 9 |
| Canada | Medium | 3 |
| Canada | Low | 13 |

I'd like to get the output table looks like:

| COUNTRY | High | Medium | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 22 | 5 | 3 |
| Italy | 43 | 21 | 8 |
| Canada | 9 | 3 | 13 |

Can anybody help me?

How to do that without using aggregation function or using but the get all values. Cause, for example, if I use min() or max() I get the max and min value and the others cells would be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you think that using min/max would leave empty cells? As there is only one value for each country/level combination then using min or max is effectively just picking that one value.

Obviously, if your source data had more than one record for each combination of country/level then you'd need to decide how to deal with it.

This SQL seems to work fine:

```
select * 
  from COUNTRY_INFO
    pivot(max(NUMBER) for LEVEL in ('High', 'Medium', 'Low'))
      as p
  order by country;
```